# Jagged / V shape Residuals vs Fitted plot

Tags: residuals

[image]What does a jagged / v-shaped residuals vs fitted plot mean? I am doing a multiple linear regression with three explanatory variables

I used a linear regression model with the data and indicators below, there are 217 data points: emissions.urban=lm(EN.ATM.METH.KT.CE~AG.LND.AGRI.K2+AG.LND.FRST.K2+SP.URB.TOTL,data=wbcc)
summary(emissions.urban)

I've posted the data below
AG.LND.AGRI.K2= Agricultural land (sq. km)
AG.LND.FRST.K2=Forest area (sq. km)
SP.URB.TOTL=Urban population
EN.ATM.METH.KT.CE=Methane emissions (kt of CO2 equivalent)

| iso3c | country | AG.LND.AGRI.K2 | AG.LND.FRST.K2 | SP.URB.TOTL | EN.ATM.METH.KT.CE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABW | Aruba | 20 | 4.2 | 46654 | NA |
| AFG | Afghanistan | 379190 | 12084.4 | 10131490 | 81510 |
| AGO | Angola | 69524.9 | 666073.8 | 21962884 | 35520 |
| ALB | Albania | 11740.81 | 7889 | 1762579 | 3160 |
| AND | Andorra | 188.3 | 160 | 67928 | 50 |
| ARE | United Arab Emirates | 3817.5 | 3173 | 8609395 | 52960 |
| ARG | Argentina | 1487680 | 285730 | 41796990 | 117850 |
| ARM | Armenia | 16773 | 3284.7 | 1876112 | 2430 |
| ASM | American Samoa | 49 | 171.3 | 48106 | NA |
| ATG | Antigua and Barbuda | 90 | 81.2 | 23927 | 200 |
| AUS | Australia | 3588950 | 1340051 | 22152761 | 139070 |
| AUT | Austria | 26528.3 | 38991.5 | 5238680 | 6660 |
| AZE | Azerbaijan | 47795 | 11317.7 | 5701802 | 43600 |
| BDI | Burundi | 20330 | 2796.4 | 1629988 | 2140 |
| BEL | Belgium | 13540 | 6893 | 11334006 | 8200 |
| BEN | Benin | 39500 | 31351.5 | 5869446 | 5530 |
| BFA | Burkina Faso | 121000 | 62164 | 6397866 | 15600 |
| BGD | Bangladesh | 92023 | 18834 | 62873466 | 83790 |
| BGR | Bulgaria | 50300 | 38930 | 5242987 | 6910 |
| BHR | Bahrain | 86 | 7 | 1523019 | 14850 |
| BHS | Bahamas, The | 140 | 5098.6 | 327359 | 230 |
| BIH | Bosnia and Herzegovina | 22110 | 21879.1 | 1608256 | 3380 |
| BLR | Belarus | 84530 | 87676 | 7470497 | 16730 |
| BLZ | Belize | 1720 | 12770.5 | 183005 | 530 |
| BMU | Bermuda | 3 | 10 | 63903 | NA |
| BOL | Bolivia | 377270 | 508337.6 | 8185478 | 25050 |
| BRA | Brazil | 2368788.01 | 4966196 | 185081854 | 416280 |
| BRB | Barbados | 100 | 63 | 89634 | 2350 |
| BRN | Brunei Darussalam | 144 | 3800 | 342330 | 8830 |
| BTN | Bhutan | 5130 | 27250.8 | 326515 | 860 |
| BWA | Botswana | 258616 | 152547 | 1666761 | 4560 |
| CAF | Central African Republic | 50800 | 223030 | 2038064 | 23200 |
| CAN | Canada | 581990 | 3469281 | 30997832 | 93980 |
| CHE | Switzerland | 15100.756 | 12691.1 | 6383962 | 4790 |
| CHI | Channel Islands | 92.2 | 10.2 | 53832 | NA |
| CHL | Chile | 156930 | 182107 | 16770077 | 13480 |
| CHN | China | 5285287 | 2199781.8 | 861289359 | 1238630 |
| CIV | Cote d'Ivoire | 212000 | 28367.1 | 13639151 | 6560 |
| CMR | Cameroon | 97500 | 203404.8 | 15279799 | 14960 |
| COD | Congo, Dem. Rep. | 315000 | 1261552.4 | 40874034 | 38620 |
| COG | Congo, Rep. | 106280 | 219460 | 3742867 | 3540 |
| COL | Colombia | 494920 | 591419.1 | 41431388 | 76700 |
| COM | Comoros | 1310 | 329.2 | 255487 | 270 |
| CPV | Cabo Verde | 790 457.2 | 370577 | 120 |  |
| CRI | Costa Rica | 17825 | 30348.7 | 4114567 | 4820 |
| CUB | Cuba | 63000 | 32420 | 8743468 | 12690 |
| CUW | Curacao | NA | 0.7 | 138059 | NA |
| CYM | Cayman Islands | 27 | 127.2 | 65720 | NA |
| CYP | Cyprus | 1309.47 | 1725.3 | 806771 | 740 |
| CZE | Czech Republic | 35230 | 26770.9 | 7923709 | 12430 |
| DEU | Germany | 166450 | 114190 | 64472284 | 53370 |
| DJI | Djibouti | 17020 | 58 | 771254 | 690 |
| DMA | Dominica | 250 | 478.7 | 51178 | 50 |
| DNK | Denmark | 26320 | 6284.4 | 5138400 | 7140 |
| DOM | Dominican Republic | 24290 | 21441 | 8953860 | 9200 |
| DZA | Algeria | 413588.47 | 19490 | 32332690 | 49550 |
| ECU | Ecuador | 54480 | 124978.3 | 11320846 | 20350 |
| EGY | Egypt, Arab Rep. | 38359.688 | 449.8 | 43781728 | 56870 |
| ERI | Eritrea | 75920 | 10552.6 | 1149669 | 3730 |
| ESP | Spain | 261833.239 | 185721.7 | 38264801 | 39940 |
| EST | Estonia | 10040 | 24384 | 921477 | 1050 |
| ETH | Ethiopia | 379030 | 170685 | 24941349 | 103110 |
| FIN | Finland | 22720 | 224090 | 4729705 | 4240 |
| FJI | Fiji | 4250 | 11400.2 | 513187 | 670 |
| FRA | France | 286601 | 172530 | 54570334 | 58340 |
| FRO | Faroe Islands | 30 | 0.8 | 20718 | NA |
| FSM | Micronesia, Fed. Sts. | 220 | 644.2 | 26378 | 60 |
| GAB | Gabon | 22126.4 | 235306 | 2005203 | 1120 |
| GBR | United Kingdom | 173508.616 | 31900 | 56395647 | 51210 |
| GEO | Georgia | 23718 | 28224 | 2208084 | 5210 |
| GHA | Ghana | 147827.4 | 79857.1 | 17820023 | 21350 |
| GIB | Gibraltar | NA | 0 | 33691 | NA |
| GIN | Guinea | 145000 | 61890 | 4842717 | 17830 |
| GMB | Gambia, The | 6050 | 2426.7 | 1512397 | 1700 |
| GNB | Guinea-Bissau | 8151.1 | 19800.1 | 869776 | 1500 |
| GNQ | Equatorial Guinea | 2840 | 24484.2 | 1025582 | 12230 |
| GRC | Greece | 61036 | 39018 | 8541900 | 9670 |
| GRD | Grenada | 80 | 177 | 41111 | 2030 |
| GRL | Greenland | 2431.1 | 2.2 | 49198 | NA |
| GTM | Guatemala | 38560 | 35278 | 8738685 | 11750 |
| GUM | Guam | 180 | 280 | 160239 | NA |
| GUY | Guyana | 12512.5 | 184153.4 | 210688 | 1540 |
| HKG | Hong Kong SAR, China | 50 | NA | 7481800 | NA |
| HND | Honduras | 33560 | 63592.6 | 5780230 | 8150 |
| HRV | Croatia | 14840 | 19391.1 | 2329285 | 3820 |
| HTI | Haiti | 18400 | 3473 | 6509478 | 4730 |
| HUN | Hungary | 52960 | 20530.1 | 7014174 | 7120 |
| IDN | Indonesia | 623000 | 921332 | 154926514 | 287500 |
| IMN | Isle of Man | 403 | 34.6 | 44980 | NA |
| IND | India | 1796740 | 721600 | 481980332 | 666510 |
| IRL | Ireland | 45160 | 7820.2 | 3179292 | 16820 |
| IRN | Iran, Islamic Rep. | 459540 | 107518.7 | 63728813 | 149690 |
| IRQ | Iraq | 92500 | 8250 | 28514939 | 16750 |
| ISL | Iceland | 18720 | 513.5 | 344066 | 530 |
| ISR | Israel | 6233 | 1400 | 8533651 | 12070 |
| ITA | Italy | 124050 | 95661.3 | 42306582 | 43670 |
| JAM | Jamaica | 4440 | 5968.9 | 1667459 | 780 |
| JOR | Jordan | 10218 | 975 | 9327507 | 6300 |
| JPN | Japan | 44200 | 249350 | 115494817 | 21110 |
| KAZ | Kazakhstan | 2160365 | 34546.8 | 10815873 | 41360 |
| KEN | Kenya | 276300 | 36110.9 | 15053275 | 40250 |
| KGZ | Kyrgyz Republic | 105413 | 13153.8 | 2429400 | 4990 |
| KHM | Cambodia | 55660 | 80683.7 | 4051341 | 20310 |
| KIR | Kiribati | 340 | 11.8 | 66405 | 20 |
| KNA | St. Kitts and Nevis | 60 | 110 | 16406 | 80 |
| KOR | Korea, Rep. | 16520 | 62870 | 42156641 | 25530 |
| KWT | Kuwait | 1500 | 62.5 | 4270563 | 6080 |
| LAO | Lao PDR | 23940 | 165955 | 2640299 | 7610 |
| LBN | Lebanon | 6580 | 1433.3 | 6069524 | 3250 |
| LBR | Liberia | 19540.4 | 76174.4 | 2634493 | 6210 |
| LBY | Libya | 153500 | 2170 | 5544510 | 37790 |
| LCA | St. Lucia | 106 | 207.7 | 34598 | 270 |
| LIE | Liechtenstein | 51.6 | 67 | 5498 | 20 |
| LKA | Sri Lanka | 28116 | 21130.2 | 4101702 | 10030 |
| LSO | Lesotho | 24333 | 345.2 | 621853 | 2320 |
| LTU | Lithuania | 29470 | 22010 | 1901682 | 3150 |
| LUX | Luxembourg | 1315.59 | 887 | 578234 | 540 |
| LVA | Latvia | 19380 | 34107.9 | 1299043 | 1940 |
| MAC | Macao SAR, China | NA | NA | 649342 | NA |
| MAF | St. Martin (French part) | NA | 12.4 | NA | NA |
| MAR | Morocco | 300690 | 57424.9 | 23450016 | 17670 |
| MCO | Monaco | NA | 0 | 39244 | NA |
| MDA | Moldova | 22571 | 3865 | 1121710 | 3310 |
| MDG | Madagascar | 408950 | 124298.1 | 10670457 | 17470 |
| MDV | Maldives | 79 | 8.2 | 219833 | 130 |
| MEX | Mexico | 1068910 | 656920.8 | 104088701 | 144610 |
| MHL | Marshall Islands | 86 | 94 | 46049 | 30 |
| MKD | North Macedonia | 12640 | 10014.9 | 1218402 | 2520 |
| MLI | Mali | 412010 | 132960 | 8891939 | 23290 |
| MLT | Malta | 103.8 | 4.6 | 497676 | 220 |
| MMR | Myanmar | 128890 | 285438.9 | 16943754 | 65790 |
| MNE | Montenegro | 2568 | 8270 | 419585 | 820 |
| MNG | Mongolia | 1134330 | 141727.8 | 2250777 | 17860 |
| MNP | Northern Mariana Islands | 30 | 243.6 | 52836 | NA |
| MOZ | Mozambique | 414138.32 | 367437.6 | 11587640 | 16850 |
| MRT | Mauritania | 396610 | 3128 | 2572517 | 6830 |
| MUS | Mauritius | 860 | 387.7 | 515916 | 1930 |
| MWI | Malawi | 56500 | 22417 | 3333777 | 11020 |
| MYS | Malaysia | 85710 | 191140.4 | 24973604 | 46580 |
| NAM | Namibia | 388100 | 66389 | 1322115 | 4510 |
| NCL | New Caledonia | 1840.3 | 8380.2 | 194500 | NA |
| NER | Niger | 466000 | 10797 | 4024595 | 29860 |
| NGA | Nigeria | 691234.5 | 216269.5 | 107106007 | 127900 |
| NIC | Nicaragua | 50650 | 34075.3 | 3909282 | 9830 |
| NLD | Netherlands | 18220 | 3695 | 16087009 | 17260 |
| NOR | Norway | 9862.97 | 121800 | 4463566 | 4850 |
| NPL | Nepal | 41210 | 59620.3 | 5995190 | 30800 |
| NRU | Nauru | 4 | 0 | 10834 | 0 |
| NZL | New Zealand | 104670 | 98925.9 | 4408037 | 32530 |
| OMN | Oman | 14588.9 | 25 | 4405789 | 5460 |
| PAK | Pakistan | 363000 | 37259 | 82094635 | 151020 |
| PAN | Panama | 22590 | 42138.4 | 2951905 | 5390 |
| PER | Peru | 236087 | 723303.7 | 25815966 | 31410 |
| PHL | Philippines | 124400 | 71885.9 | 51950201 | 67660 |
| PLW | Palau | 43 | 414.1 | 14652 | 20 |
| PNG | Papua New Guinea | 11900 | 358557.6 | 1193981 | 11310 |
| POL | Poland | 145120 | 94830 | 22786800 | 47540 |
| PRI | Puerto Rico | 1689 | 4963.3 | 2989009 | NA |
| PRK | Korea, Dem. People's Rep. | 26300 | 60300.9 | 16081083 | 18710 |
| PRT | Portugal | 35739.9 | 33120 | 6833619 | 11320 |
| PRY | Paraguay | 218190 | 161022.6 | 4435221 | 29070 |
| PSE | West Bank and Gaza | 2969.200134 | 101.4 | 3685020 | NA |
| PYF | French Polynesia | 455 | 1494.6 | 174090 | NA |
| QAT | Qatar | 670 | 0 | 2859020 | 8110 |
| ROU | Romania | 134140 | 69290.5 | 10451921 | 23780 |
| RUS | Russian Federation | 2154940 | 8153116 | 107723564 | 849570 |
| RWA | Rwanda | 18117 | 2760 | 2257829 | 2910 |
| SAU | Saudi Arabia | 1736290 | 9770 | 29343564 | 44170 |
| SDN | Sudan | 681861.6 | 183595.5 | 15458183 | 58850 |
| SEN | Senegal | 88780 | 80681.6 | 8057514 | 10750 |
| SGP | Singapore | 6.6 | 155.7 | 5685807 | 4150 |
| SLB | Solomon Islands | 1170 | 25229.7 | 169453 | 410 |
| SLE | Sierra Leone | 39490 | 25348.8 | 3423961 | 4610 |
| SLV | El Salvador | 14791.2 | 5838.8 | 4763725 | 3990 |
| SMR | San Marino | 23 | 10 | 33089 | NA |
| SOM | Somalia | 441250 | 59800 | 7333290 | 19430 |
| SRB | Serbia | 34640 | 27226.5 | 3899416 | 12400 |
| SSD | South Sudan | 285332 | 71570 | 2261021 | 34170 |
| STP | Sao Tome and Principe | 440 | 519 | 162955 | 30 |
| SUR | Suriname | 840 | 151962.9 | 388053 | 1370 |
| SVK | Slovak Republic | 18890 | 19259 | 2934665 | 4360 |
| SVN | Slovenia | 6120 | 12378.3 | 1157547 | 1980 |
| SWE | Sweden | 30090 | 279800 | 9108648 | 4580 |
| SWZ | Eswatini | 12220 | 4975.6 | 280423 | 1500 |
| SXM | Sint Maarten (Dutch part) | NA | 3.7 | 40812 | NA |
| SYC | Seychelles | 15.5 | 337 | 56661 | 90 |
| SYR | Syrian Arab Republic | 139210 | 5220.8 | 9708489 | 12770 |
| TCA | Turks and Caicos Islands | 10 | 105.2 | 36242 | NA |
| TCD | Chad | 502380 | 43130 | 3863362 | 53990 |
| TGO | Togo | 38200 | 12092.7 | 3543299 | 3450 |
| THA | Thailand | 221100 | 198730 | 35898129 | 84140 |
| TJK | Tajikistan | 47277 | 4238 | 2623424 | 5520 |
| TKM | Turkmenistan | 338380 | 41270 | 3167338 | 49580 |
| TLS | Timor-Leste | 3800 | 9211 | 412936 | 5280 |
| TON | Tonga | 350 | 89.5 | 24415 | 100 |
| TTO | Trinidad and Tobago | 540 | 2281.9 | 744725 | 1280 |
| TUN | Tunisia | 97430 | 7027.3 | 8221976 | 6420 |
| TUR | Turkey | 378020 | 222203.6 | 64186247 | 47400 |
| TUV | Tuvalu | 18 | 10 | 7549 | 10 |
| TZA | Tanzania | 396500 | 457450 | 21042571 | 62650 |
| UGA | Uganda | 144150 | 23379 | 11414209 | 33250 |
| UKR | Ukraine | 413290 | 96900 | 30721277 | 62950 |
| URY | Uruguay | 140159 | 20310 | 3317930 | 20940 |
| USA | United States | 4058103.538 | 3097950 | 272364755 | 622590 |
| UZB | Uzbekistan | 255777 | 36896.6 | 17258430 | 105930 |
| VCT | St. Vincent and the Grenadines | 70 | 285.4 | 58837 | 70 |
| VEN | Venezuela, RB | 215000 | 462309 | 25102966 | 72340 |
| VGB | British Virgin Islands | 70 | 36.2 | 14669 | NA |
| VIR | Virgin Islands (U.S.) | 40 | 199.1 | 101974 | NA |
| VNM | Vietnam | 121688 | 146430.9 | 36346227 | 87750 |
| VUT | Vanuatu | 1870 | 4423 | 78400 | 510 |
| WSM | Samoa | 757 | 1616.7 | 35494 | 300 |
| XKX | Kosovo | 5700 | NA | NA | NA |
| YEM | Yemen, Rep. | 233877 | 5490 | 11306428 | 8590 |
| ZAF | South Africa | 963410 | 170500.9 | 39946775 | 45140 |
| ZMB | Zambia | 238360 | 448140.3 | 8204576 | 17870 |
| ZWE | Zimbabwe | 162000 | 174445.8 | 4792105 | 11850 |

Comment: You don't provide much information, and it's hardly helpful to make guesses about what could be going on. Instead explain your problem, the data, what is the outcome variable, what are the three predictors, what is the model that you've fitted, etc....

Comment: Thanks for posting the data. It seems clear that  CPV Cabo Verde needs editing before the data can be used.  Two columns have been mushed into one. (The total land area of the country is 4033 sq. km according to Wikipedia.)

Comment: There are many possible analyses of these data.  I fixed Cabo Verde, as above, and ignored missing values. My suggestions: They are all essentially size variables for countries covering a wide range. There are some zeros. As a brute force method that won't appeal universally, I pushed them all (outcome and predictors) through `log1p()` $= \ln(1 + v)$ and then plain regression works well enough and the residual versus fitted plot looks very well behaved.

Answer (score 2):

A dip (or hump) in the residuals curve is a sign of non-linearity. It means that you might bet a better model using some quadratic terms.

But that is not the most striking issue shown by your graph. The very non-uniform distribution of the predicted values is more important. The few very large values will make a big impact on the regression coefficients because of the use of least-squares as the loss function.

There are several ways of addressing this:

- ignore very large values as "outliers"
- use an L1 loss function
- transform the value to be predicted before making the model

In this case the third option looks best - if you make a linear regression for $\log y$ instead of $y$ you might get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to @chrishmorris's helpful answer, although I am never in favour of dropping outliers because they are awkward and much more in favour of working on logarithmic scale.

It is all too easy to over-interpret a "smooth" which for high fitted values is summarizing only a very few residuals and utterly dependent on what is seen within a smoothing window, even if a data point is down-weighted somehow as it enters or leaves a window. So, the V shape is probably dependent in the right-hand half of the plot on just about the 5 residuals visible as individuals.

Two rather different stories are broadly consistent with each other and the data, on this information:

1. You would be better off with transforming $y$ or perhaps even better off with a generalized linear model with logarithmic link, such as Poisson regression.
2. The regression is doing a fair job of following the main trend of the data, but uncertainty is bound to accompany severe skewness of the response, and there may be nonlinearity better modelled otherwise.

How many data points are there here? Is it possible to post the data?

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions - there are 217 data points

emissions.urban=lm(EN.ATM.METH.KT.CE~AG.LND.AGRI.K2+AG.LND.FRST.K2+SP.URB.TOTL,data=wbcc)
summary(emissions.urban)